# Screen Clipping, The Size of Clipped Area

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

I am using OneNote in order to take screen clipping. It is so easy and helpful for me. But I am searching for an additional quality  such that when I start screen clipping, I want to see the size of the clipped rectangular in terms of pixels while doing clipping. Is it possible to arrange this setup? Thanks.

Comment: I am in One Note Desktop 365 and have such screen clips. I am pretty sure you cannot determine the size of the image in One Note.

Comment: Well, Is there any other solution or application that I can use for this purpose? @John.

Comment: I looked through my pages and do not see any way to get the size.

Comment: Okay @John. Thanks anyway!